# Does "GET search/tweets" return all tweets from past week?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, sentiment-analysis

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

From what I see in the twitter documentation, it only limits the number of requests per window from the past week. My question is there any limit on the number of tweets returned?

For example, I make ONE request call of `search/tweets` with a search term `Trump`. I believe there can be millions of tweets that contains the term `Trump` in the past week. Does this single request call return millions of tweets to me? Or does it sample according to some limits?

Comment: Try it and see. Did you try it? SO isn't for doing experiments for you. You're supposed to get as far as you can on your own and ONLY when you are stuck beyond believe you run to SO with your tail between your legs for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear that you'll only get 15 Tweets by default, but you can increase that to 100 per page of results, step through the results page by page. It also says:

> There are limits to the number of Tweets which can be accessed through
>   the API.